# Abstraction of the Dao Pattern

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, dao, abstraction

I am doing some research on abstraction, and I am failing to find what I am looking for. It is either I am not looking right, or I am looking for something that is not possible.

Lets say I have abstract class `Animal`...

```
public abstract class Animal {
   private String name;
   private String owner;
}
```

Now, I can have some animals extending Animal.

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
   private string additionalAttribute;

   public Dog(String name, String owner, String additionalAttribute) {
     super(name, owner); 
     this.additionalAttribute = additionalAttribute;
   }

}
```

The assumption is that there are many more animals with additional attributes specific only to that particular animal type, which the superclass `Animal` does not know about.

I want to create a DAO to crud all these different animals. I figure it would be inefficient to create a DAO for all the different Animals. So I create one DAO for the abstract class `Animal`.

```
public class AnimalDao {
   private Database db;

   public AnimalDao(Database db) {
      this.db = db;
   }

   public void create(Animal animal) {
      db.save(animal);
   }

   public Animal read(String id) {
     db.get(id);
   }
}
```

When I create an instance of this dao and add a Dog, then try to get it, I have to do some casting to the type of animal which I saved and want to get. But after I get the Animal which may be a Dog, Cat or whatever, those additional attributes are not there.

To a certain degree, I understand why that is. My question is, is there a way to create a Dao, that can save all the subclasses of my superclass? Or do I have to create a Dao for each subclass? Which would be very stupid because the implementation would be exactly the same.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can use some reflective code to instrospect your classes or use an ORM framework.

Comment: I understand that this can be done via some frameworks, however, that would defeat the purpose. I am doing this to know how it can be done through my own implementation

Comment: The way you are doing you will need to have one DAO for each subclass. There is no magic.

Comment: Mhh i see. That is very weird. One would think there is a way around this.

Comment: As I said, you can use reflection, but doing so is the same that implementing your own ORM framework.

Comment: This is not a standard thing to do. E.g. what should the DAO do? Should it find the correct table in the DB, one table each animal, and shove it there? In that case a Visitor pattern is a solution for storing, then for reading you'd search in your tables (or use an extra table remembering which id is which animal), then instantiate based on where you're reading from. Sounds ... terrible, but would work. If you have a single table for all animals, you probably have to save `type` anyway. Either way, upon reading you indeed *have* to cast based on what animal you expect.

Comment: _One would think there is a way around this._ What attributes does a dog have that other other animals do not?  Can those _seemingly_ unique dog attributes be abstracted across all animals?  Use composition rather than inheritance.